# ASP.NET page won't remove UI elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I'm working with an aspx page, where once I click on a button, some calls are executed in the background and I display the returned information on the webpage. I do this by adding this information to a panel:

```
panel.controls.add(label)
panel.controls.add(anotherpanel)
```

Problem is that once I click the button again, and I get some new objects from the background calls the UI elements (those labels and panels) still remain visible and my new information is just added after the previous one.

I would like to have all the previous information gone once I press the new button.

I've tried `panel.controls.clear()`, but it doesn't do anything.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: are you calling the clear after the Page Init?

Comment: No, i'm calling the clear as the first thing after the button is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting a breakpoint and check to see that it is not the background calls returning the previous information along with the new ones?

I asked because items that were added programmatically, by itself, shouldn't persist across postbacks.

Comment: Have a correct answer! I thought I actually looked over that quite thoroughly, but now I checked it again, and yeah, since I was using a singleton WCF service, I was not re-initializing a value every time I was making the call. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to declare `label` and `anotherpanel` in the actual markup, and set their `visibility` to `false`. Then, just set the visibility to `true` and replace their values in your codebehind as you acquire results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris, but that doesn't help, since I don't know how many objects I get back from that background call. Could be 10 strings, but it could as well be 100. That's why I have to create the panels and labels in code.